# Admob Test Ads (rewarded ads) are not shown on a real device after build

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, admob, ads, game-development

> I got a problem with admob rewarded ad. When I run the project everything works great, but after building the project, the test ad (rewarded ad) is not shown on the real device while the test interstitial and
> test banner ads are working fine. Has anyone encountered a similar problem?
> I think the problem is in the ad request

---

```
using System;
using GoogleMobileAds.Api;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using GoogleMobileAds.Common;

public class Rewarded : MonoBehaviour
{
RewardedAd rewardAd;
public Button watchAd;
string rewardId;
void Start()
{
    RequestRewardedAd();
}

//make button interactable if video ad is ready
void Update()
{
  
    if (rewardAd.IsLoaded())
    {
        watchAd.interactable = true;
    }
}

void RequestRewardedAd()
{
 #if UNITY_ANDROID
    rewardId = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917";
 #elif UNITY_IPHONE
    rewardId = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917";
 #else
    rewardId = null;
 #endif
    rewardAd = new RewardedAd(rewardId);

    //call events
    rewardAd.OnAdLoaded += HandleRewardAdLoaded;
    rewardAd.OnAdFailedToLoad += HandleRewardAdFailedToLoad;
    rewardAd.OnAdOpening += HandleRewardAdOpening;
    rewardAd.OnAdFailedToShow += HandleRewardAdFailedToShow;
    rewardAd.OnUserEarnedReward += HandleUserEarnedReward;
    rewardAd.OnAdClosed += HandleRewardAdClosed;


    //create and ad request
    if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey("Consent"))
    {
        AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();
        rewardAd.LoadAd(request); //load & show the banner ad
    }
    else
    {
        AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().AddExtra("npa", "1").Build();
        rewardAd.LoadAd(request); //load & show the banner ad (non-personalised)
       }
    }

    //attach to a button that plays ad if ready
     public void ShowRewardedAd()
  {
    if (rewardAd.IsLoaded())
    {
        rewardAd.Show();
    }
}

//call events
public void HandleRewardAdLoaded(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    //do this when ad loads
}

public void HandleRewardAdFailedToLoad(object sender, AdErrorEventArgs args)
{
    //do this when ad fails to loads
    Debug.Log("Ad failed to load" + args.Message);
}

public void HandleRewardAdOpening(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    //do this when ad is opening
}

public void HandleRewardAdFailedToShow(object sender, AdErrorEventArgs args)
{
    //do this when ad fails to show
}

public void HandleUserEarnedReward(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    //reward the player here
    //RevivePlayer();
}

public void HandleRewardAdClosed(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    //do this when ad is closed
    RequestRewardedAd();
}
```

}